# D language unsigned hash of string

Tags: hash, d

I am a complete beginner with the [D language](http://dlang.org/).

How to get, as an `uint` unsigned 32 bits integer in the D language, some hash of a string...

I need a quick and dirty hash code (I don't care much about the "randomness" or the "lack of collision", I care slightly more about performance).

```
 import std.digest.crc;
 uint string_hash(string s) {
    return  crc320f(s);
 }
```

is not good...

(using `gdc-5` on Linux/x86-64 with phobos-2)

Comment: Unfortunately, D doesn't expose the the hash function it uses for string keys in associative arrays...

Comment: You could try to look at these http://pokristensson.com/code/strmap/strmap.h and http://pokristensson.com/code/strmap/strmap.c

Comment: Why doesn't the crc32 work? Is it a bad value or just a type mismatch ?

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: yes it does: `TypeInfo.getHash`.

Comment: @beerboy Oh. TIL... You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A really quick thing could just be this:

```
uint string_hash(string s) { 
    import std.digest.crc; 
    auto r = crc32Of(s); 
    return *(cast(uint*) r.ptr); 
}
```

Since `crc32Of` returns a `ubyte[4]` instead of the `uint` you want, a conversion is necessary, but since `ubyte[4]` and `uint` are the same thing to the machine, we can just do a reinterpret cast with the pointer trick seen there to convert types for free at runtime.

Comment: `ubyte[4]` and `uint` are not exactly the same thing! `uint` usually has a different alignment than `ubyte[4]`. Your code might break on architectures which do not support unaligned loads. There's at least one D-supported architecture which will be affected: ARMv5. (Such casts also break strict aliasing rules. However, as the D specification does not specify aliasing rules compilers are conservative and never use strict-aliasing optimizations, so this is not a real issue.) The correct way is to use a union.

Comment: oh you're right, I didn't even think about alignment. The union would be a better way.

Comment: I think `read` from `std.bitmanip` module would be safer to convert this array to `uint`

Answer (score 8):

While Adams answer does exactly what you're looking for, you can also use a union to do the casting.
This is a pretty useful trick so may as well put it here:

```
/**
  * Returns a crc32Of hash of a string
  * Uses a union to store the ubyte[]
  * And then simply reads that memory as a uint
  */
uint string_hash(string s){ 
    import std.digest.crc;
    union hashUnion{
        ubyte[4] hashArray;
        uint hashNumber;
    }   
    hashUnion x;
    x.hashArray = crc32Of(s); // stores the result of crc32Of into the array.
    return x.hashNumber;      // reads the exact same memory as the hashArray
                              // but reads it as a uint.
}
```